# Check reactions of a specific message on Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to check the reactions of a **specific** message by storing its message id. I'm using discord.js.

**The problem**

> The problem is that when using my code, I get this error: ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined***. Maybe it's because it's an embed? What I am trying to do is getting the id of the sent embed and writing it into a file. Then, in the code that handles the reactions, I should get the id wrote on the file, and test if that is the correct message the reaction has been added to.

**My code**

```
async function tembed(message) {
  
    const mention = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (mention.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "dittatore")) {
          message.channel.send(`Cannot eject **${mention}**.`);
          message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
        }
        if (mention.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "dittatore")) return;
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
        const testembed = {
          color: '#7A2F8F',
          title: 'test',
          description: `${mention} this is a test embed`,
          footer: 'test footer',
        };
        let sent = await message.channel.send({ embed: testembed }).then(async (embedMessage) => {
          await embedMessage.react('✅');
          await embedMessage.react('❌');
        });
        let id = sent.id; //TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
        fs.writeFile('/home/pi/botstuff/testembed.txt', id, (err) => { 
          if (err) throw err;
        });
        console.log(`wrote ${id} on file`);
        const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("770735002182877224");
        channel.send(`${mention}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are doing:

```
let sent = await message.channel.send({ embed: testembed }).then()
```

That's the wrong way to do it. `async/await` is essentially an easier way of using Promises; in essence, it is a *replacement* for `.then()`. So that above code is the equivalent of doing `message.channel.send().then().then()`, meaning `sent` is either now still a `Promise` (with a `.then()` method) or simply `undefined` instead of the `message` object you want it to be.

The simple solution to this is to stop trying to use two different methods of handling Promises at the same time. Use either `async/await` or `.then()` but don't use both at once. `async/await` is much easier to use, so we'll go with that in this example solution.

```
async function tembed(message) {
    const mention = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (mention.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "dittatore")) {
        message.channel.send(`Cannot eject **${mention}**.`);
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
        return;
    }

    message.channel.bulkDelete(1);

    const testembed = {
      color: '#7A2F8F',
      title: 'test',
      description: `${mention} this is a test embed`,
      footer: 'test footer',
    };

    let sent = await message.channel.send({ embed: testembed });        
    await sent.react('✅');
    await sent.react('❌');
    let id = sent.id; //TypeError no longer occurs
    
    fs.writeFile('/home/pi/botstuff/testembed.txt', id, (err) => { 
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    console.log(`wrote ${id} on file`);
    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("770735002182877224");
    channel.send(`${mention}`);

}
```

I additionally removed a few unnecessary redundancies from your provided code (both in your duplicate checks for the `dittatore` role and your defining of both a `sent` and `embedMessage` variable when both are supposed to be the same message).